# How to execute a proper (and effective) introduction? I'm not yet on the proposal

Tags: attracting-clients

Making a good first impression is important. As a stranger from your target client, what are the good points to include in your introduction and what are the bad ones to avoid? Are there indirect and direct approaches on building a connection that will prevent you being seen as on a hard sell?

Comment: `As a stranger` as in you don't know your target market formally, or you don't know who your target market *is*?

Comment: What I mean - You know your client very well from your research, and you are the one who is stranger to them.

Answer (score 4):

When you approach someone as prospective client, you have very short window to capture his attention. I would follow this generic guideline. If you manage to complete all four steps succesfully while keeping prospects attention, you have got yourself pretty good lead:

1) **Prefer personal introduction to written one.** Expecially if your expertise is flooding every room you enter. If you have at least mediocre people skills, use them to your advantage. If you dont, hire someone to do selling for you who has those.

2) **Capture attention with bold, yet believable claim (which has to be true).** It can even contain a catch - if that catch is actually the punchline that will gain you credibility. How about "I can ensure that you will be at first page of google search for any keyword you choose next day". Thats pretty bold statement, that captures attention. Punchline being, that you can do it using PPC add and that you will help your client to set goals, that are actually helping his "bizz" because their impact on the "bizz" can be measured...

3) **Tell him your offer.** After all doing business is about having an offer "you give me this, I will give you that". That offer must clearly contain values for the client to see immediately they are worth the cost

4) Now comes the hardest part - **you must give the prospect reason to trust you.** If you present awesome offer, they will be looking for the catch. If there is one, explain it openly. If there isnt, explain how it is possible you can make such a good offer (you have awesome skills, you have licenses to awesome software that makes your work fast and top-quality, etc.

And always remember - sometimes all the skills you have are not enough. SOmetimes prospect wont be interested despite the fact that your offer is best deal he could ever make. Dont worry about that, it comes with the job. If your offer is great and you really care about the benefits you are bringing to your customers, you will succeed with this approach.